# Weird Case Sensitive Issue in Java

Tags: java, jvm, java-7, case-sensitive

When I try and load an image and change a letter from lower to upper case or vice versa, the image shows up perfectly in the IDE I use (via JDK 1.7) but when I export a runnable JAR of the same code to run on the JVM (1.7) all of a sudden there is a case sensitivity issue, where the filename has to be exact.

Here is example code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    JLabel im = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Sammy\\Documents\\Aurora\\Onix 2 original\\app_Background.png"));
    frame.add(im);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Changing `app_Background.png` to `app_background.png` seems to make no difference when I run it in Netbeans, the image shows up in the same way.

However when I run the code from the JVM through command prompt or just a runnable JAR the image doesn't show up unless the filename is proper.

My question is why isn't the same case sensitivity behaviour happening when running inside an IDE and when running outside of one?

Comment: Both run on the same OS?

Comment: It could be a jre issue.  The netbeans you are using might use the jre that comes with the jdk.  When it is exported as a jar file, you are using a different jre.  There is a reason why there are so many releases of the jre/jdk.

Comment: Yes @assylias on Windows 7

Comment: @PeteBelford Using JDK and JVM 1.7 Update 25 so that can't be an issue

Answer (score 4):

Java is strictly case sensitive and  whereas the OS(I guess `Windows`) file system many not.

This discussion goes over as why this happens:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198946

Comment: If both tests are run on the same OS, that would not explain the behaviour.

Comment: @assylias This would explain it as reading from a `.jar` file is case sensitive whereas reading a file in Windows is not.

Comment: @UwePlonus The file name is on a hard drive, not within the jar. Not sure I understand what you meant.

Comment: @assylias if a file is embedded into a `.jar` file the name of the file in the `.jar` file is case sensitive!

Comment: @UwePlonus ok but in the example the file is not embedded in a jar file.

Comment: @UwePlonus Actually I made this example to demonstrate my issue, but the real issue i've spent an hour looking for was for an image embedded in the JAR. Image was not showing when running JAR and after an hour turns out I didn't use proper case in file name...

Comment: I find it hard to believe this is Netbeans fault. I can believe Case sensitivity of paths to images embedded in JARs have a different behaviour to images on hard drive. Any source pointing to this @UwePlonus ?

Comment: @SammyGuergachi this is not NetBeans fault and also not Javas fault. This is Windows fault as for Windows the case in file names does not matter. I develop my Java programs on Linux which is case sensitive and had never such a problem.

Comment: Thats believable, I had never noticed till now. Thanks, if you post an answer elaborating i'll mark it as the answer to this question :)